# If A is a subgroup of the normalizer of B in G, then B is normal in A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $A, B$ are subgroups of $G$.

Is it true that $A \leq N_G(B)$ $\Rightarrow$ $B \trianglelefteq A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, Take $S_{3}$. and take B=$A_{3}$. Then $N_{G}(B)=S_{3}$. Now take $A=\{\ e, (1 2) \}\ $. $A \leq N_{G}(B)= S_{3}$ but B is not normal in A.

Answer (score 0):

If $B$ is a subgroup of $A$, then the answer of your question is yes. However, $B$ need not be a subgroup of $A$ under the condition $A\le N_G(B)$. For example, consider $G = Q_8=\{\pm1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$, a quaternion group, and take $A = \langle -1\rangle$ and $B=\langle i\rangle$.